# Vim workflow for projects on remote machines

Tags: ide, ssh

I have several projects on several different VMs which I can `ssh` into. I also have a nice Vim workflow with plugins like `fzf` and `coc.nvim` on my local macbook.

I'd like to learn what is the best way to working on a remote project using my local IDE.

I've tried working on files using `scp://` but this doesnt seem to work very well. `netrw` is slow, and tools like `fzf` are not available.

I know that I could use a dotfiles management tool to recreate my local IDE on a remote machine, but this seems laborious and not a good general solution.

I've also heard of `rsync`, but don't know anything about it yet. Maybe this is a good solution.

I'd like to know what other developers do in this situation?

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced this is on-topic or narrow enough, though I'm not yet convinced enough that it's off-topic/too-broad to close it immediately. Not sure how to craft the question better, either. (Part of my issue is it doesn't seem like it has much to do with vim, per se. This is evidenced by my solution would be: make those project git repositories, clone them, and develop locally, at least if editing over SSH is a no-go. `netrw` has not been unuseably slow in my experience.)

Comment: Maybe a more focussed question would be "how can I use fzf.vim when the project is on a remote machine". Thanks for the thoughtful comment. I'd hoped that vim, or a vim plugin would provide functionality such that nerdtree and fzf.vim work for  projects on remote machines.

Comment: If `scp://` is slow due to general latency issues than you probably don't have any option that doesn't involve having an actual local copy of the project hierarchy. If that's _not_ the case then you might try [mounting the remote folder as a file system using sshfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202919/213782). That's a common approach.

Comment: For me this is a valid question and one that would need good answers.

Comment: I’ve been using unison (which is built on top of rsync) to keep the local and remote versions in sync. Im going to write a script that includes a file watcher that will trigger the unison sync whenever a file changes. This should remove any need to think about syncing. I wanted to reduce cognitive overhead to simply writing code and running code. I didn’t want a “syncing code” step.

Comment: I used `sshfs` for a long time, but actually learned to use vim originally for editing files on remote machines without going through the loops of mounting. sshfs will have issues of you put your machine to sleep for the night and would like to start anew in the morning. If you do this regulary enough, I actually suggest to set up some dotfile management (I personally use `yadm` which is actually fairly simple if you don't need fancy stuff) and `tmux` (maybe `screen`) to handle session being killed.

Answer (score 2):

sshfs is a handy utility that allows one to locally mount a remote project, solving the problem. Granted, it's not as elegant as the plugins actually just working seamlessly on remote files.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).